# JLayeredPane. Dynamically change layer index of JPanel

Tags: java, swing, focus, jlayeredpane

I'm using a JLayeredPane to position my JPanels 3-dimensional, so that I may achieve a "zoom" effect when someone clicks on a jpanel, I there for need to dynamically change the layer index so the clicked component is always on "top".

```
JPanel jp = new JPanel();

JLayeredPane jlp = new JLayeredPane();
jlp.add(jp, new Integer(50));
```

Here is the first time I place my JPanel, but how can I "reach" it again and change the index?

Comment: Perhaps, you should keep the components in some kind of `Map`, associated with there current layer, or just keep them in a `List` of some kind. You can also use `JLayeredPane#getLayer` to get it's current layout. Assuming you're using a `MouseListener`, the `MouseEvent` returns the `source` of the event, but you can use `getComponent` as a connivance.

Comment: I am saving the JPanel in a list. But is the layer index not a function of the  JLayeredPane object?

Comment: So you need to maintain a reference of the `JLayeredPane` as an instance field

Answer (score 2):

[JLayeredPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html) has both a "Layer" and a "Position" concepts.
You can place all your components on the same Layer, but with different positions.
0 is the top-most position within the layer and -1 is the bottom-most position.
The JLayeredPane methods [moveToFront](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html#moveToFront(java.awt.Component)), [moveToBack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html#moveToBack(java.awt.Component)) and [setPosition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html#setPosition(java.awt.Component,%20int)) can be used to re-position a component within its layer.

Here's an example for this approach which brings to the front the component which the user clicks:

```
JLayeredPane pane = new JLayeredPane();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Jlabel-"+(i+1));

    lbl.setOpaque(true);
    lbl.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if (pane.getPosition(lbl) != 0) 
                pane.moveToFront(lbl);
        }
    });
    lbl.setFont(lbl.getFont().deriveFont(48f));
    lbl.setForeground(new Color(i*10, i*50, i*50));
    lbl.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2));
    lbl.setBounds(i*100, i*25, lbl.getPreferredSize().width, lbl.getPreferredSize().height);
    pane.add(lbl, 0, new Integer(i+1));
}
```

[image]